# regular expression for special case

Tags: java

The postcode must be of the form of two capitals, up to two digit numbers, followed by a space, up to two digits and two capital letters. For example, GU2 7XH is permitted but GU22 777XH is not, GU22 8AB is permitted but GU222 88AB is not.
can someone help me acheive this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{1,2}\s[0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]{2}
```